# How to override ALT+N event for SharePoint 2016

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

How to override ALT+N event for SharePoint 2016 Document Library to don't open standard upload document form

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.altKey && (e.which == 78)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code
    console.log("Alt+N won't work here!");
  }
});
```

Comment: after adding this fragment of code i see alert and after that standard document form when press ALT+N

Comment: I see message 'Alt+N won't work here!' in browser console and after that standard upload document form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120525/discussion-between-mr-7-and-dmitry).